# SUM of a YTD-value by Year for several selected years

Tags: sql, sharepoint, mdx, reportbuilder

I am trying to put together an SQL statement that returns the SUM of a value by Year for several selected years, but on a year to date basis. In other words, running the report by selecting years I need the value for the selected years on a year to date basis. This could be something like this: By selecting the years 2015, 2014 until 2010 the Report should give 2015 value ytd of 25.02.2015, 2014 ytd of 25.02.2014 and so on.

Yet I only figured out how to select the Dates for each year to date value manually., but clearly the I was thinking. However, I was hoping to have some of this work handled with my SQL Statement using the selected years Parameter and add month and day somehow.

Has anyone ever tackled this type of problem with an SQL statement, and if so, what is the trick that I am missing?

My current sql statement for ytd data is similar to the following:
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Turnover YTD], [Measures].[Order Intake YTD] } ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DateDate, CONSTRAINED)

This works perfectly for the one year, but still I am seeking the solution for several years.

As described above my desired result would be: after choosing several fiscal years (e.g. 2010-2015) I will get following values:
2015 Sales Turnover YTD Order Intake YTD on date today
2014 Sales Turnover YTD Order Intake YTD on date today one year ago 
and so on..

Comment: You want MDX or SQL code for this?

Comment: I normally build my reports with reportbuilder so they are SQL, I guess. If possible I would prefer an SQL solution, but a mdx solution would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script against AdvWrks that calculates the equivalent YTD totals for each of the years ON ROWS:

```
WITH 
  SET [NonEmptyDates] AS 
    NonEmpty([Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS) 
  SET [LastNonEmptyDate] AS 
    Tail([NonEmptyDates]) 
  SET [SetDaysInCurrentYear] AS 
    Descendants
    (
      Exists
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
       ,[LastNonEmptyDate].Item(0).Item(0)
      ).Item(0)
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[NumDaysInCurrentYear] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [LastNonEmptyDate].Item(0)
     ,[SetDaysInCurrentYear]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[EquivYTD] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      Head
      (
        Descendants
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
        )
       ,[Measures].[NumDaysInCurrentYear]
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[EquivYTD]
  } ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Damn, that did not work. SO I got your, I guess it works, but I always get this message: "Too many arguments were passed to the Aggregate function. No more than 2 arguments are allowed."

Comment: @SimonPrestel - where are you trying to test this script? SSRS?

Comment: Yes, I am using in SSRS to build and test the reports.

Comment: @SimonPrestel - I just pasted into the mdx query window and it works straight away for me!